# Oracle container database 12c, connecting using JDBC

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c

I'm trying to learn how to use Oracle Container database, and just do basic JDBC connections. I installed a dockerised version of Oracle:

https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-database-enterprise-edition

Which according to the data sheet comes set up with a CDB database called ORCLCDB and a PDB database called ORCLPDB1.

So I figured out I can connect to it like this:

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1555:ORCLCDB

with username sys, password Oradoc_db1, and setting the special internal_logon jdbc parameter equal to "sysdba" to avoid the error "local oracle CDB: ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER"

And I figured out I can switch to the PDB by entering this:

> ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=ORCLPDB1

And I can then create a new user:

> CREATE USER MYUSER IDENTIFIED BY MYPASSWORD1

But then I'm stuck. I think there should be some way to connect directly to the PDB using a JDBC connect string. Every time I google about this, it talks about tnsnames blah blah, but people who use JDBC connections, are typically using Tomcat on a server, or otherwise don't have the Oracle Client installed. They expect to be able to connect to Oracle just with the thin driver installed, nothing else.

I've tried the obvious using:

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1555:ORCLPDB1
> with username myuser or sys, but I always get:

ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

At this point I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a SERVICE_NAME in order to connect to an Oracle container database

Please alter your connect string like this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1555/ORCLPDB1
```

- A SERVICE_NAME is denoted by a "/"
- A SID (SystemIDentifier) is denoted by a ":" (not to be used)

Note! Default listener port is 1521, not sure why you specifically want a different port.

Best of luck!

Comment: I tried that, it results in a slightly different error: "ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor"

Comment: The reason the port is non standard is because it's docker and I exposed a different port. I suppose I could have kept the port the same, but I chose to use a different one.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the correct answer is this...

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/ORCLPDB1.localdomain

Then I can connect as SYS using the method above. If I want to connect as the created user, I also need...

> grant create session to myuser;

and then, turn off the internal_logon jdbc parameter.